# Widget weather, by user zip?

Tags: widget, weather

Anyone know of a good one for web? The only widget I've been able to find that works for the web is accuweather, but their zip code often generates the wrong city, so it's inaccurate.

I don't mind more, hard coding it, but I'm not aware of the code per say. Or working examples. Someting that auto displays user weather by their zip code

Any suggestions would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Alternative I can think of, the [Yahoo YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and [Wunderground API](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api). This 2 are not widget based but API to return you the raw weather information (for example, in json format). You have to do your own formatting.

Yahoo YQL is free but honestly I don't know the limitation of how many queries you are able to make per day. Yahoo YQL will require you to query using the woeid. For instance,

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20u=%27c%27%20and%20woeid=56069&format=json
```

The woied of 56069 points to Oranjestad, Aruba. The list could be retrieval from [this weather station file](https://www.ip2location.com/free/weather-station-code). But, you will also need to purchase a commercial package from IP2Location to get the weather station code for matching.

The second option is Wunderground. The have a developer version API but limited to 500 calls per day. Their API is only required the country code and city name for the query. For example,

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/conditions/q/TH/Bangkok.json
```

Whereby TH is the ISO3166 country code, Bangkok is the city. For this option, you can either use a free location web service, such as [IPInfoDB](http://www.ipinfodb.com/) or database version such as [IP2Location LITE DB](https://lite.ip2location.com/), or any location service providers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the city name by IP address. Try the services of https://geoip-db.com

A jQuery example (although other code snippets can be found on their webpage too)  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOIP DB - City name by IP address</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( location ) {
                $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                $('#state').html(location.state);
                $('#city').html(location.city);
                $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
            }
        });     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```